# Titan DB 1.0.0 : Cannot import Json file into titan TinkerPop 3.x

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

How make import from JSON  file into titan DB , when i use geolocation property ??

I'm working with Titan DB TP3 - version 3.0.1-incubating

```
gremlin> Gremlin.version()
==>3.0.1-incubating
gremlin>
```

and using GeoShape index property (geolocation) , 
trying to export and import into new DB.

My steps are as following:

```
   //export : 
        tg = TitanFactory.open(‘../conf/titan-db.properties’)
        tg.io(IoCore.graphson()).writeGraph('/var/backups/PRODUCTION_DATA_27_10_16.json');



  //import to new DB:
       tg.io(IoCore.graphson()).readGraph('/var/backups/PRODUCTION_DATA_27_10_16.json');
```

but unfortunately got exception :

```
gremlin> tg.io(IoCore.graphson()).readGraph('/var/backups/PRODUCTION_DATA_27_10_16.json');
Property value [{type=Point, coordinates=[33.0, 32.0]}] is of type class java.util.LinkedHashMap is not supported
Display stack trace? [yN] y
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property value [{type=Point, coordinates=[33.0, 32.0]}] is of type class java.util.LinkedHashMap is not supported
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Property$Exceptions.dataTypeOfPropertyValueNotSupported(Property.java:159)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.verifyAttribute(StandardTitanTx.java:564)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.addProperty(StandardTitanTx.java:716)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.property(AbstractVertex.java:142)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.property(AbstractVertex.java:23)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.Attachable$Method.lambda$createVertex$26(Attachable.java:296)
```

Please any solutions .. .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are running into this [Issue 1183](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/1183): *Titan 1.0.0 GraphSONWriter.writeGraph JsonMappingException*, which has already been fixed. Try building the `titan11` branch from source code. If you need directions for building it, review the steps in this Titan [mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/S9j5Zclumd8/mZp-6OmoFwAJ).

If you want to patch the Titan 1.0.0 build with the [serialization fix](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/commit/6dfc816d821a7739398e5cebc1e999d75c866c19) and not move up to `titan11`, try this instead ([discussed here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/bTLQGsVZm_E/c-6DbTEfBQAJ)):

```
git clone https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan.git
cd titan
git checkout 1.0.0
git cherry-pick 6dfc816d821a7739398e5cebc1e999d75c866c19
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Dgpg.skip=true -Paurelius-release
unzip titan-dist/titan-dist-hadoop-1/target/titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip
```

Comment: Off-topic: What is the ETA of the 1.1 release? Do you happen to know?

Comment: Datastax (who acquired Aurelius) doesn't have a time line for this. You can see this message on the Titan mailing list: "The Aurelius team, who built TitanDB, has moved on to DataStax to develop DSE Graph, the successor to TitanDB. Contact support for help on DSE Graph or use StackOverflow."

Comment: However there is an effort underway to reinvigorate the Titan community as an open project.

Comment: ^^ JanusGraph project has been established at The Linux Foundation http://janusgraph.org/